# Should the pointer being passed to free() point to the start of the allocated space?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

Say I used `malloc` to request a free space. The variable `ptr` points to the created memory space. In my code the value of `ptr` is changed to access different locations in my allocated space.

Calling `free(ptr)` , after `ptr` has been changed, would not be correct, no?. What I should do instead is to create a replica of `ptr` after `malloc`. This new pointer should be used instead in the `free` function call. Is that right?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

> Calling `free(ptr)` , after `ptr` has been changed, would not be correct, no?

That is the correct understanding. It would not be correct.

> What i should do instead is to create a replica of `ptr` after `malloc`. This new pointer should be used instead in the `free` function call. Is that right?

You have the following choice here:

1. Keep the original variable and use a copy to point to different locations of the `malloc`ed data. Call `free` using original variable.
2. Make a copy, use the original variable to point to different locations of the `malloc`ed data. Call `free` using copy.
3. Keep the original pointer. Use an index to access different locations of the  `malloc`ed data. Call `free` using original variable.

Regardless of the way you access different locations of the data returned by `malloc`, the value of the pointer that was returned by `malloc` must be used in the call to `free`.

Comment: a third option is pointer arithmetic. keeping the pointer as is, and having an index

Comment: @sp2danny, Indeed. Thanks for the reminder. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your understanding and suggested solution are correct. Moreover, according to the C11 standard,

> 7.22.3.3 The `free` function
>
> ...if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the behavior is undefined

So trying to `free` somewhere in the middle of the memory you allocated causes undefined behavior and likely breaks your program.

Answer (score 1):

As per Chapter 7.20.3.2, `c99` standard, 2nd paragraph [emphasis mine]

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, ***if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the `calloc`, `malloc`, or `realloc` function,*** or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, ***the behavior is undefined.***

So, you cannot pass a pointer to `free()` which is not returned by `malloc()` or family. You're very right.

To get your job done, at the beginning, you've to make a copy of the orginal pointer returned by `malloc()` and once you're done with using the memory, you need to call `free()` with the previously stored value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You understood right. When `ptr` is changed to point to different location then calling `free` will memory allocated by `malloc` will not be deallocated.
You need to keep a copy of the returned pointer.